# CKEditor - make links clickable (when in read-only mode)

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4.5.4 and I have a button that toggles the read only state of the editor using this command:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'text', { height: '200px' });
editor.setReadOnly(false);
```

What I want to do is make all links inside the CKEditor clickable when the editor is in `read-only` mode - when `read-only` is false, I want the links to behave normally.

At the moment I am struggling to make the links clickable at all - inspecting them I can see they are valid HTML (at one point I thought the links in the CK Editor was just blue text with an underline) - I am assuming that CKEditor is preventing the default action of these links.  Is this toggle-able?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intentional behavior as opening links causes some problems. Here is the part of the code which [prevents opening links in read-only mode](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/editable.js?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L978).

See also https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/6032 and https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10912 for broader context and issues caused by this behaviour.

---

You may add you own link handler like:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { readOnly: true } );

editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    var editable = editor.editable();
    editable.attachListener( editable, 'click', function( evt ) {
        var link = new CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath( evt.data.getTarget(), this ).contains( 'a' );
        if ( link && evt.data.$.button != 2 && link.isReadOnly() ) {
            window.open( link.getAttribute( 'href' ) );
        }
    }, null, null, 15 );
} );
```

With HTML like:

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">  
    <p>Foo Bar Baz <a href="http://ckeditor.com">CKEditor</a></p>
</textarea>
```

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/f1ames/pen/JyJRQg?editors=1010) to test it. You may also add additional checks to see if `href` is not empty, etc.

---

This is not a perfect solution as ideally we would like to browser handle opening clicked links natively. However, in most scenarios it should work as expected.
Also it may cause some security issues as the user is able to manipulate the link href (during editing) in any way.